# Why is there an error, "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'..."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm creating an MVC ASP.NET form using Visual Studio 2012, C#, and Razor.  After the "Submit Query" button is pressed, There is an error, "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Age'," and it's on this line in the View:

> Age @Html.DropDownList("Age")

Here is the View:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>MVC Cheese Survey</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

        @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        <div>First Name @Html.TextBox("FirstName")
             Last Name @Html.TextBox("LastName")
            <br />
            Address @Html.TextBox("Address")
            Address @Html.TextBox("Address")
            City @Html.TextBox("City")
            State @Html.TextBox("State")
            Zip @Html.TextBox("Zip")
            Phone @Html.TextBox("PhoneNumber")
            Email @Html.TextBox("Email")
            Age @Html.DropDownList("Age")

        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
        }
        @ViewData["FirstName"]
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcCheeseSurvey.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {   
            List<string> AgeList = new List<string>();
            AgeList.Add("0-17");
            AgeList.Add("18-21");
            AgeList.Add("22-25");
            AgeList.Add("26-35");
            AgeList.Add("36+");

            ViewData["Age"] = new SelectList(AgeList);

            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string FirstName, string LastName)
        {
            ViewData["FirstName"] = FirstName;
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both versions of the `Index` action need to populate the "Age" data for the `ViewData`, like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{   
    List<string> AgeList = new List<string>();
    AgeList.Add("0-17");
    AgeList.Add("18-21");
    AgeList.Add("22-25");
    AgeList.Add("26-35");
    AgeList.Add("36+");

    ViewData["Age"] = new SelectList(AgeList);

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string FirstName, string LastName)
{
    ViewData["FirstName"] = FirstName;

    List<string> AgeList = new List<string>();
    AgeList.Add("0-17");
    AgeList.Add("18-21");
    AgeList.Add("22-25");
    AgeList.Add("26-35");
    AgeList.Add("36+");

    ViewData["Age"] = new SelectList(AgeList); 

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! One last thing:  How do you get the FirstName & LastName text boxes to be blank on the Post? (I still want the FirstName to post back outside of the text box, like it is now.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure your ViewData is filled when the POST method is handled and the same view is returned.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private void EnsureAge()
    {
        List<string> AgeList = new List<string>();
        AgeList.Add("0-17");
        AgeList.Add("18-21");
        AgeList.Add("22-25");
        AgeList.Add("26-35");
        AgeList.Add("36+");

        ViewData["Age"] = new SelectList(AgeList);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string FirstName, string LastName)
    {
        EnsureAge();
        ViewData["FirstName"] = FirstName;
        return View();
    }

}
```

The values are retained as 'feature' of your browser. You can clear them excplicitly by calling adding the following lines to your submit bitton in your view:

```
<input type="submit" 
       name="submit" 
       onclick="document.getElementById('FirstName').value='';document.getElementById('LastName').value='';"/>
```

Comment: No problem, I also checked setting autocomplete='off' on the input element and returning a 205 status code  (reset content) instead of a 200 but neither worked for me on IE10. Didn't check other browsers though.

Answer (score 0):

I've had exacltly the same issue.
In my case it was missing ViewBag item.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AddAnswer(Answer answer){ 
       // insert to database
       return View();
    }
```

This should look like

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AddAnswer(Answer answer){ 
       // insert to database
       ViewBag.ListOfQuestions = ListOfQuestions;
       return View();
    }
```

My view code is:

```
         <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.QuestionId, ViewBag.ListOfQuestions as SelectList, "--SELECT--")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QuestionId)
        </div>
```